# PowerBI - Power Query Fetch credentials from Azure Vault

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

We have a requirement to fetch data from a rest api into powerbi and schedule a refresh every night. The rest api support jwt authentication so it needs header with xapikey and access token.

I have managed to write a function in power query to get access token from our auth endpoint and able to inject access token for the rest api call and it works fine with powerbi-desktop. I have published the report to powerbi cloud.

The auth endpoint require username and password, we would not like to store this details in .pbix file and publish to cloud but instead use azure key vault and powerbi to fetch details at runtime.

Please advise ?

Answer (score 1):

Power Automate has a great Azure Vault connector.

You could make a simple 3-action flow:

[image]

A post to that URL will json back the secret/credentials.

Now, here is the goofy part - hide that URL in a permissioned location (Onedrive, Sharepoint, etc). Have your pbi pickup from that location, using privileged credentials. Now the URL and the credentials get picked up at runtime, and neither is persisted in PBIX.

I am assuming that there is an available premium PAutomate env in which to spin up that flow, of course. But, given that you already have an azure vault, that seems like a standard `PBI+` toolkit to have at that point.

Comment: Nice, I have to test this at work!